# Хочу собрать проект breakpad, но получаю ошибку в python. UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec

Tags: python, c++, telegram

Пытаюсь сбилдить проект google breakpad.

Вот список комманд которыя я выполняю

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad
cd breakpad
git checkout bc8fb886
git apply ../patches/breakpad.diff
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest src/testing
if "%X8664%" equ "x64" (
set "FolderPostfix=_x64"
) else (
set "FolderPostfix="
)
cd src\client\windows
gyp --no-circular-check breakpad_client.gyp --format=ninja
cd ..\..
ninja -C out/Debug%FolderPostfix% common crash_generation_client exception_handler
ninja -C out/Release%FolderPostfix% common crash_generation_client exception_handler
cd tools\windows\dump_syms
gyp dump_syms.gyp --format=ninja
cd ..\..\..
ninja -C out/Release%FolderPostfix% dump_syms
```

и получаю следующую ошибку

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\ninja.py", line 2467, in CallGenerateOutputForConfig
    GenerateOutputForConfig(target_list, target_dicts, data, params, config_name)
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\ninja.py", line 1973, in GenerateOutputForConfig
    cl_paths = gyp.msvs_emulation.GenerateEnvironmentFiles(
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\msvs_emulation.py", line 1068, in GenerateEnvironmentFiles
    f.write(env_block)
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 6682-6683: character maps to <undefined>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 552, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 530, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\ninja.py", line 2493, in GenerateOutput
    pool.map(CallGenerateOutputForConfig, arglists)
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\TBuild\ThirdParty\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 6682-6683: character maps to <undefined>
```

Так вот, это же библиотеки которые лежат на гитхабе, они я думаю должны собираться 100%. Это не мой код, так что я в нем не мог допустить ошибку.
Эта ошибка появляется из за не правильной кодировки, но где она не правильная? мне кажется этот код не билдится только на моей машине. Как можно решить мою проблему?

Comment: У вас виндовая кодировка в системе cp1251, а в библиотеках видимо UTF-8 где-то используется. Как сказать скрипту, что дефолтная кодировка должна использоваться UTF-8 я не знаю.

Comment: Звучит правдиво, только как указать кодировку по умолчанию я тоже не знаю, пробовал поставить переменную среды
set PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"
не помогло, ошибка та же

Comment: Плохо ещё, что у вас питон древний. 2.7 уже не поддерживается толком.

Comment: 2.7 так только папка называется
на самом деле стоит Python 3.9.6

Comment: Понятно. Чтоб запутать противника. Логично.

Comment: Попробуйте это ещё: "You can use the Python UTF-8 Mode to change the default text encoding to UTF-8. You can enable the Python UTF-8 Mode via the `-X utf8` command line option, or the `PYTHONUTF8=1` environment variable." Взял отсюда: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Спасибо большущее,
Поставил переменную среды set PYTHONUTF8=1

и все взлетело )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итого, поставил переменную окружения и все взлетело:

```
set PYTHONUTF8=1
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)